# What kind of process to optimize images for the Web?

Tags: images, photoshop

I always optimized images for the Web using Photoshop and some simply steps:

- dpi changed to 70
- save for the web
- jpeg with quality very high or
  high depending on the final weigth of the image

Publishing for websites in fields as fashion they make to me noticed how some so done images they have imperfections.

Expecially comparing them with the original ones.

What kind of process do you use to optimize images?

Comment: Sorry but the question is broad and opinionated as there is no right or wrong methods, only preferred and personal recommendations.  You may have however find similar questions on the [UX stack regarding image compression](http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=compression) and [image formats](http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=image+format)